# Why does ssh-add show what I type when run via ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When I do

```
$ ssh -A ssh.example.com ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```

it shows what I am typing when I type my passphrase.

Python is slightly more helpful about what's going on:

```
$ ssh ssh.example.com "python -c 'from getpass import getpass; print(getpass())'"
/usr/lib64/python3.6/getpass.py:91: GetPassWarning: Can not control
echo on the terminal.   passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

Is there a way around this?

I can do `stty -echo` before I do the ssh command, but I'd be typing the command without seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `-t` to emulate a terminal , so `ssh-add` can execute some `tty` settings to prevent the display of your password .

So in your case :

```
ssh -A -t ssh.example.com ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
```